# Malformed dots when using listings

Tags: code, sourcecode, lstlisting

How is it possible to compile such page?

```
\begin{lstlisting}
⡂⡀⣀⢀⣄⡀⣰⡉⡀⠀⡀⡀⣀⠀⢀⣀⢀⣄⡀⡂⢀⣀⡀⢀⢀⡀⠀⡰⣀⠀⣀⠀⡂⡀⣀⢀⣄⡰⡀⢠⠂
⡇⡏⠀⡇⡇⠀⢸⠀⡇⢀⡇⡏⠀⡇⣏⠀⠀⡇⠀⡇⣏⠀⣹⢸⠁⢸⠀⡇⢈⠷⡁⠀⡇⡏⠀⡇⡇⠀⡇⢼⠀
⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠁⠈⠀⠈⠁⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠉⠀⠈⠁⠁⠈⠉⠁⠈⠀⠈⠀⠱⠉⠀⠉⠀⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠱⠁⠘⠄
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⢤⡀⡤⠀⣀⣀⣀⠀⢤⡀⡤⠀⠀⢰⠀⠀⢹⠠⠀
⠀⠀⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠒⠒⠒⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠉⢹⠉⠁⢸⢀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⠀
⠀⠀⠀⣄⢄⠤⢄⢴⠤⢠⠀⢠⢠⡠⢠⡠⢄⠀⢤⡀⡤⢺⡖⠐⣷⠂⠊⢉⡆
⠀⠀⠀⡇⠸⣍⣉⠸⣀⠸⣀⢼⢸⠀⢸⠀⢸⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣴⣋⡀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

⢱⠀
⢸⠁
⠊
\end{lstlisting}
```

Because there is an error:

```
`! Package utf8x Error: MalformedUTF-8sequence.See the utf8x package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...��⣀⠀⣀⠀⡂⡀⣀⢀⣄⡰⡀⢠`⠂
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX; use a font you have supporting Braille.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\braille}{Apple Braille}

\begin{document}

{\obeylines\braille
⡂⡀⣀⢀⣄⡀⣰⡉⡀⠀⡀⡀⣀⠀⢀⣀⢀⣄⡀⡂⢀⣀⡀⢀⢀⡀⠀⡰⣀⠀⣀⠀⡂⡀⣀⢀⣄⡰⡀⢠⠂
⡇⡏⠀⡇⡇⠀⢸⠀⡇⢀⡇⡏⠀⡇⣏⠀⠀⡇⠀⡇⣏⠀⣹⢸⠁⢸⠀⡇⢈⠷⡁⠀⡇⡏⠀⡇⡇⠀⡇⢼⠀
⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠁⠈⠀⠈⠁⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠉⠀⠈⠁⠁⠈⠉⠁⠈⠀⠈⠀⠱⠉⠀⠉⠀⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠱⠁⠘⠄
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⢤⡀⡤⠀⣀⣀⣀⠀⢤⡀⡤⠀⠀⢰⠀⠀⢹⠠⠀
⠀⠀⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠒⠒⠒⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠉⢹⠉⠁⢸⢀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⠀
⠀⠀⠀⣄⢄⠤⢄⢴⠤⢠⠀⢠⢠⡠⢠⡠⢄⠀⢤⡀⡤⢺⡖⠐⣷⠂⠊⢉⡆
⠀⠀⠀⡇⠸⣍⣉⠸⣀⠸⣀⢼⢸⠀⢸⠀⢸⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣴⣋⡀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

⢱⠀
⢸⠁
⠊
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are great and a surprise with your idea!!!! +1.

Comment: `! The font "Apple Braille" cannot be found.` How can I install it?

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich As I said, you need a font that you have on your system and supports Braille. Find one on the net, there are many: google for “braille font”.

Comment: I installed this one http://www.fontspace.com/philing/braille-normal . But while compiling I have errors like `Missing character: There is no ⣀ in font Braille Normal/OT!
` and nothing printed.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428769/correct-braille-font