# Correct braille font

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

Have a Ubuntu 16.04 OS.
I installed Braille font from here http://www.fontspace.com/philing/braille-normal.

I want to compile this code gotten from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428745/malformed-dots-when-using-listings/428746#428746):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braille}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\braille}{Braille Normal}

\begin{document}
{\obeylines\braille
⡂⡀⣀⢀⣄⡀⣰⡉⡀⠀⡀⡀⣀⠀⢀⣀⢀⣄⡀⡂⢀⣀⡀⢀⢀⡀⠀⡰⣀⠀⣀⠀⡂⡀⣀⢀⣄⡰⡀⢠⠂
⡇⡏⠀⡇⡇⠀⢸⠀⡇⢀⡇⡏⠀⡇⣏⠀⠀⡇⠀⡇⣏⠀⣹⢸⠁⢸⠀⡇⢈⠷⡁⠀⡇⡏⠀⡇⡇⠀⡇⢼⠀
⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠁⠈⠀⠈⠁⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠉⠀⠈⠁⠁⠈⠉⠁⠈⠀⠈⠀⠱⠉⠀⠉⠀⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠱⠁⠘⠄
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⢤⡀⡤⠀⣀⣀⣀⠀⢤⡀⡤⠀⠀⢰⠀⠀⢹⠠⠀
⠀⠀⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠒⠒⠒⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠉⢹⠉⠁⢸⢀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⠀
⠀⠀⠀⣄⢄⠤⢄⢴⠤⢠⠀⢠⢠⡠⢠⡠⢄⠀⢤⡀⡤⢺⡖⠐⣷⠂⠊⢉⡆
⠀⠀⠀⡇⠸⣍⣉⠸⣀⠸⣀⢼⢸⠀⢸⠀⢸⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣴⣋⡀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

⢱⠀
⢸⠁
⠊
} 

\end{document}
```

But I have an errors like:

```
Missing character: There is no ⣠ in font Braille Normal/OT!
Missing character: There is no ⠛ in font Braille Normal/OT!
Missing character: There is no ⣄ in font Braille Normal/OT!
Missing character: There is no ⠀ in font Braille Normal/OT!
Missing character: There is no ⠉ in font Braille Normal/OT!
Missing character: There is no ⢹ in font Braille Normal/OT!
```

And as I result I have an empty page.

What braille font I should install for correct compiling?

Comment: egreg's mwe does *not contain* `\usepackage{braille}`. Maybe that's the problem. I can not test at the moment! And compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

Comment: egreg used another font, I have some doubt that yours is unicode encoded. Try what happens if you type normal chars like "a".

Comment: here is a list of fonts which support the relevant unicode block: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/braille_patterns/fontsupport.htm. I tried your example with \newfontfamily{\braille}{DejaVu Serif} and it worked fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, thank you, it helped me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments.